# StackPanel ignore HorizontalAlignment issue XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have issue, i just try to make chat window with messages(From right incoming and from left sended out) but seems like stackpanel ignore HorizontalAlignment. Here's my code

```
<ListView>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                            FontSize="22"
                            Text="{Binding MessageTextIn}"              
                        />
                            <TextBlock
                            FontSize="10"
                            Text="{Binding MessageTimeIn}" Padding="10"
                        />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                FontSize="22"
                                Text="{Binding MessageTextOut}"
                            />
                            <TextBlock
                                FontSize="10"
                                Text="{Binding MessageTimeOut}" Padding="10"
                            />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Seems like i do something wrong but what exactly?

Thanks for any help!

Sorry if i ask something stupid.

Comment: Have you set the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView`?

Comment: @DzumoPro what do you mean by _stackpanel ignore HorizontalAlignment_? One `StackPanel` is aligned to the left side of `ListView` and second to the right side

Comment: Can you share any image of your expected output? Seems the code is correct.

Comment: Sure, sorry was afk here image http://i.imgur.com/UPzirDd.png

Comment: And i need In to Left and Out to Right. Thanks

Comment: Put a BackgroundColor on those `<StackPanel>s` and you will understand why that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your ItemContainer only has a right alignment (by default).
Set the ItemContainerStyle of your Listview:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```